# SQL Server how to pass table column like ID to scalar function in same database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to pass all id values to the function. How can I do this?

Like if I can loop on all id and pass all id for these fun which scalar function

```
empFn(emp.[id])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use table valued parameters to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

There are many many examples on the net.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, you should use [CROSS APPLY](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/)

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.employees emp
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM dbo.empFn(emp.[id]))
```

Comment: i want pass ids for 8 sclar fns

SELECT *
FROM dbo.employees emp
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM dbo.empFn(emp.[id]),fn2(id),fn3(id),fn4(id),fn5(id))

Comment: Can't understand that, sorry

Comment: I think you might mean CROSS APPLY

Comment: Take a look at this example for formatting. http://www.sql-programmers.com/table-valued-function-using-cross-apply.aspx